# How to paste multi-line input into Jupyter console?

Tags: macos, ipython, jupyter, ipython-magic

The %paste magic for pasting multi-line input works with IPython 2, but fails with Jupyter console (on Mac OSX El Capitan).

```
~ > jupyter console
Jupyter Console 4.1.0


In [1]: %paste
ERROR: Line magic function `%paste` not found.

In [2]:
```

Going through the output of %lsmagic that lists all the magic commands indeed doesn't show %paste.

I tried to directly paste, but the indentation gets messed up, so something like %paste is needed apparently. Checking the [official documentation](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/jupyter-console/latest/jupyter-console.pdf) (updated just 5 days ago) the word "paste" is not even mentioned.

So, how do you paste multi-line input to the console?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ok. Found the solution. Jupyter console has a %cpaste magic that behaves a little different than the previous %paste but get the job done.

```
%cpaste:
Paste & execute a pre-formatted code block from clipboard.

You must terminate the block with '--' (two minus-signs) or Ctrl-D
alone on the line. You can also provide your own sentinel with '%paste
-s %%' ('%%' is the new sentinel for this operation).

The block is dedented prior to execution to enable execution of method
definitions. '>' and '+' characters at the beginning of a line are
ignored, to allow pasting directly from e-mails, diff files and
doctests (the '...' continuation prompt is also stripped).  The
executed block is also assigned to variable named 'pasted_block' for
later editing with '%edit pasted_block'.

You can also pass a variable name as an argument, e.g. '%cpaste foo'.
This assigns the pasted block to variable 'foo' as string, without
dedenting or executing it (preceding >>> and + is still stripped)

'%cpaste -r' re-executes the block previously entered by cpaste.
'%cpaste -q' suppresses any additional output messages.

Do not be alarmed by garbled output on Windows (it's a readline bug).
Just press enter and type -- (and press enter again) and the block
will be what was just pasted.

IPython statements (magics, shell escapes) are not supported (yet).

See also
--------
paste: automatically pull code from clipboard.

Examples
--------
::

  In [8]: %cpaste
  Pasting code; enter '--' alone on the line to stop.
  :>>> a = ["world!", "Hello"]
  :>>> print " ".join(sorted(a))
  :--
  Hello world!
```

Comment: This is not for jupyter console but for ipython, so you're not answering the question